# Vectorize the equation `A[x, y] = A[x, y] / sqrt(A[x, x] * A[y, y])` to reduce computational time

Tags: python, numpy

Having a symmetry matrix `A` with the shape of `N x N`, I want to perform the transformation `A[x, y] = A[x, y] / sqrt(A[x, x] * A[x, y])` to produce a new matrix. Currently, the below snippet is my implementation.

```py
def gen_new_mat(mat: np.ndarray):
    new_mat = np.copy(mat)
    for i in range(new_mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i + 1, new_mat.shape[0]):
            alpha = np.sqrt(new_mat[i, i] * new_mat[j, j])
            new_mat[i, j] /= alpha
            new_mat[j, i] = new_mat[i, j]

    return new_mat
```

This runs correctly. However, it computes **very slow** (~12 secs when `N ≈ 3800`).

How can I **speed up** this process by using some libraries designed for matrices related-tasks (e.g., `numpy`)? I can only think of that but any other approaches are very appreciated. Thank you guys so much!!

Comment: So is this transformation is not applied to the diagonal elements?

Comment: Are you sure the code is implementing that transformation formula? Why does `alpha` depend on `new_mat` rather than `mat`, and why do you assume the resulting matrix will be symmetrical, when the formula has the asymmetrical component `A[x, x]`?

Comment: I think the title has a typo: `sqrt(A[x, x] * A[x, y])) -> should be `sqrt(A[x, x] * A[y, y])`. That or the code has a typo

Comment: @SurajShourie oh yeah, that's the typo on the title. My mistake.

Comment: @SurajShourie there is a step involving the manipulation of diagonal elements later on, but it's straightforward, so I omitted it from the question for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @JonnyJack Got it, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @SurajShourie yeah, it works like a charm!! I have upvoted for you. Tysm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need to vectorize the operation of the denominator that can be done using: `np.multiply.outer(mat.diagonal(), mat.diagonal()`

So the function is:

```
def gen_new_alpha_np(mat: np.ndarray):
    return mat/ np.sqrt(np.multiply.outer(mat.diagonal(), mat.diagonal()))
```

**Note** This assumes that you want the divide operation on the diagonal entries as well, if you don't you need to add something like `new_mat.diagonal() = mat.diagonal()` at the end

##### Time comparison:

I compared both functions for 200x200 matrix:

1. New function:

```
def test():
    mat = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(200,200))
    mat = mat.astype(np.float32)
    return mat/ np.sqrt(np.multiply.outer(mat.diagonal(), mat.diagonal()))

 
# timeit statement
print(timeit.timeit("test()", number=1000, globals=globals()))
```

Output:

```
0.5923793000001751
```

2. Old Function:

```
def test():
    mat = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(200,200))
    mat = mat.astype(np.float32)
    new_mat = np.copy(mat)
    for i in range(new_mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i + 1, new_mat.shape[0]):
            alpha = np.sqrt(new_mat[i, i] * new_mat[j, j])
            new_mat[i, j] /= alpha
            new_mat[j, i] = new_mat[i, j]

    return new_mat 

 
# timeit statement
print(timeit.timeit("test()", number=1000, globals=globals()))
```

Output:

```
34.02517700000021
```

As you can see the numpy operations are much faster

Comment: For large `N`, it seems that using `einsum` is _slightly_ faster, e.g., for a 3800x3800 64bit float matrix `x` (on my machine): `x / np.sqrt(np.multiply.outer(x.diagonal(), x.diagonal()))` is timed at 176ms, whereas `x / np.sqrt(np.einsum("ii,jj->ij", x, x))` is timed at 169 ms.

Comment: @MattPitkin Tysm, I will consider this when implementing.

Comment: @JonnyJack you can also use the ```out``` kwarg in many numpy functions to make this even faster by avoiding allocating a new array for each operation. For the einsum code above this could be like: ```denom = np.einsum("ii,jj->ij", x, x)
    denom = np.sqrt(denom, out=denom)
    np.divide(x, denom, out=denom)``` . For the 3800x3800 array used above this reduces the computation time from 82.9ms to 67.5 for me!

Comment: @Nin17 nice trick!!